# Replace part of string in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace all the column name in the dataframe where column name contains value in count. I have written the following code but it's not working, whereas if in place count in str.replace if i just write '5' then it runs. How can I fix this issue?

```
count=Final['Rate'].max()
count=str(count)
Final.columns = Final.columns.str.replace('count', 'Final')
```

Comment: How is it "not working" ?- elaborate. What is your expected result? What are the column names?

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the DF ?

Comment: I mean the code executes but all the columns which contains 5 in the columnname they are not being replace with 'final'

Comment: `Final.columns.str.replace(count, 'Final') ` ?

Comment: @Rakesh, I tried that too but still it don't reflect in the dataframe

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what it is that you want? What does 'Final' look like and what does count look like (I take it that it should just contain '5')?

Comment: The Final dataframe have columns like Rate, Name, cash1, cash2, cash3, interest1, interest2, interest3. I want to replace cash3 as cashfinal, interest3 as interestfinal. There will be as many interest and cash as there is maximum value in rate

Comment: Can you please help ?

Comment: So you just want to replace cash3 with cashFinal (if 3 is the max value), and leave cash1, cash2, etc. as it is?

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `count`? Is it realy the value/string that you expect, or does `Final['Rate'].max()` give you a different number than what is in your column names? Because otherwise the code should work (after you change the last line to: `Final.columns.str.replace(count, 'Final')`)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you wrote count as a string instead of a variable.
try:

```
Final.columns.str.replace(count, 'Final')
```

instead of:

```
Final.columns.str.replace('count', 'Final')
```

At the moment you search for the substring 'count' and if it exists, you replace it with 'Final'.

If this doesn't solve the problem, please edit the question to make it more clear what the exact problem is.